# Is it possible to fill in a relative filepath in regedit?

Tags: regedit

I don't know how to fill in a regedit filepath without it being the full path.

Note: I'm new to regedit

So i have a registrykey in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT which has an URL Protocol which is supposed to execute a file i have on my pc, which looks like this:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHSu0.png)

- SE: has URL Protocol
- command: has filepath location of what its supposed to execute

The registrykey works fine when i have a set location like "D:\Download dump\myFile.exe". But i want people who have my file to be able to move it to different locations without having them to manually adjust it in the regkey.